# Getting value error on scatter() of mplot3d : arguements xs and ys must be of the same size. But they have the same size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, mplot3d, valueerror

I am trying to plot a scatter plot using mplot3d but the scatter method gives me value error: 'xs' and 'ys' must be of the same size.
When I print their types and sizes, they appear perfect. I am unable to figure out whats wrong.

Here is the part of my code : 
'mat2' is 512 *X* 4 matrix that is already computed.

```
mat2 = np.array(mat2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
co = []

xx = mat2[:,:1]
yy = mat2[:,:2]
z = mat2[:,:3]
co = mat2[:,:4]

#printing the size and types of the arguments to the scatter()
print(str(len(xx))+str(type(xx))+' '+str(len(yy))+str(type(yy))+' '+str(len(z))+' '+str(len(co)))

ax.scatter(np.array(xx), np.array(yy), z=np.array(z), c=np.array(co), cmap=plt.hot())
```

Here is a screenshot of the output that I get -
[ValueError Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHAhW.png)

Any help ?

Comment: When inquiring about an error, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I am sorry. New here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xx` and `yy` are not the same size. Instead of printing the length, you need to print the shape.

```
print(xx.shape)
```

You will observe that `xx` is of shape `(512, 1)` and `yy` is of shape `(512,2)`. Therefore `yy` has two columns and thus twice as many entries as `xx`.

Since it seems that you want to plot a scatter of the second column of `mat2` against the first, you should create `xx` and `yy` as such:

```
xx = mat2[:,0]
yy = mat2[:,1]
```

The same is of course true for the other arrays `z` and `co`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.